# Has Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick been moved in v4.2.0?

Tags: chart.js

I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onClick')" for the following code:

```
var original = Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick;
```

It worked in chart.js v2.

Answer (score 1):

As of Chart.js release 3.x

- `global` namespace was removed from `defaults`. So `Chart.defaults.global` is now `Chart.defaults`.
- `legend`, `title` and `tooltip` namespaces were moved from `Chart.defaults` to `Chart.defaults.plugins`.

For further information, please consult section **Defaults** in **3.x Migration Guide** at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  After I changed the code to "var original = Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.onClick;" , I still got the same error. Any idea? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to my problem in the Legend documentation:
"The doughnut, pie, and polar area charts override the legend defaults. To change the overrides for those chart types, the options are defined in Chart.overrides[type].plugins.legend."

As I am working on doughnut chart, I changed the code to:
`var original = Chart.overrides.doughnut.plugins.legend.onClick;`

and it works.